# Extending an Interface in other in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I need to extend one interface into another.

```
interface InterfaceToExtend {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

export interface PersonInfo {
  xyz: {
    place: string;
  };
  abc: {
    place: string;
  };
  def: {
    place: string;
  };
}
```

Is there any way to extend interface `InterfaceToExtend` into each of xyz, abd, def

Answer (score 0):

```
One way I found out is: 

interface InterfaceToExtend {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

export type PersonInfo = {
  xyz: InterfaceToExtend & {
    place: string;
  };
  abc: InterfaceToExtend & {
    place: string;
  };
  def: InterfaceToExtend & {
    place: string;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just make a new interface that extends from the base interface (so you don't have to use an intersection type):

```
interface InterfaceToExtend {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

interface ExtendedInterface extends InterfaceToExtend {
  place: string;
}

export type PersonInfo = {
  xyz: ExtendedInterface; 
  abc: ExtendedInterface;
  def: ExtendedInterface; 
}
```

If you wanted to make a type without defined keys where every property value implements that interface, you can type the keys and values:

```
interface InterfaceToExtend {
  name: string;
  address: string;
}

interface ExtendedInterface extends InterfaceToExtend {
  place: string;
}

export type PersonInfo = { [key: string]: ExtendedInterface };
```

Comment: you say "a union type" but presumably you mean "an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) type", right?

Comment: Correct. I always mix those two up. Will update answer, thanks